# Stop command execution after a while and execute next command in a shell script

Tags: bash, shell, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

I want to create a script which does the following:

1. Creates a Kafka server
2. Create a topic on Kafka
3. Start producing messages on created topic

And my script is looks like this:

```
docker run -p 2181:2181 -p 9092:9092 --env ADVERTISED_HOST=localhost --env ADVERTISED_PORT=9092 spotify/kafka
bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1 --topic my_topic
jq -rc . messages.json | bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic my_topic
```

But first command's execution process never ends and it can't go to second step. How can I understand that Kafka server is ready, and how can I execute next command after that?

Comment: Use /bin/timeout, or use a different process rather than a pipe.

Comment: Hi Mert, can you pipe your docker command output to a file and save it? Check this file to see if there are any strings in there which you can consume in an IF-ELSE condition to proceed to Step 2 ?
Ref: https://www.scalyr.com/blog/how-to-redirect-docker-logs-to-a-single-file

Answer (score 0):

You can add the `-d` option to `run` to run the container without attaching to it, allowing your script to continue immediately. This raises the problem of knowing how long to wait before the server is ready for whatever request your shell script makes. A crude fix is to insert a call to `sleep` to wait however long you deem necessary.

```
docker run -d ...
sleep 10  # Ten seconds should be plenty
bin/kafka-topics.sh ...
```

Comment: As we are unable to predict the wait time, "sleep" does not seem to be the best solution here.

Comment: Then you'll need some way to query the server to see when it is safe. I'm not familiar with Kafka myself; but allowing the `docker` command to complete is a necessary first step.